# Как активизировать плагин NASM Assembly Language в IntelliJ IDEA CE?

Tags: intellij-idea, nasm

Нужно поработать с ассемблерным кодом в среде IntelliJ IDEA CE.
Установил плагин [NASM Assembly Language](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9759-nasm-assembly-language). Но ничего не изменилось.
Как запустить ассемблер в этой ide ?

Comment: Плагин добавляет подсветку, отображение структуры кода (в окошке Structure) и прочее. Чтобы сам nasm запустить - устанавливаете его, запускаете из терминала. Поддержки запуска средствами IDE нет, насколько я вижу по описанию. Для упрощения сборки можно Makefile использовать, например.

Comment: nasm установлен: "NASM version 2.15.05". использовать Makefile можно и без ide. Я думал, что для ассемблера получу среду разработки, а не только подсветку. Получается, что в IntelliJ IDEA с ассемблером ничего не выйдет ?

Comment: Можно. По сути IntellijIDEA тут будет использоваться максимум как тяжелый редактор кода. Не уверен, даже что рефакторинг поддерживается. Я бы взял что-нибудь полегче, типа vscode.

Comment: "Получается, что в IntelliJ IDEA с ассемблером ничего не выйдет?" - может и выйдет, но на мой взгляд это будет просто очень тяжелый редактор кода для ассемблера)

Comment: не нашел кнопки завершения дискуссии, поэтому скажу здесь: понятно, спасибо.